# How can I change the text on the 404 not found view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm setting up an API with Laravel. When I enter a route that does not exist I get redirected to a view that says 404 | Not found.

How could I change this view to `abort( response()->json('Not Found', 404));` so that the person that tries to access the API via another application get a JSON response saying Not Found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You may publish Laravel's error page templates using the
>   vendor:publish Artisan command. Once the templates have been
>   published, you may customize them to your liking:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create a `404.blade.php` file under `resources/views/errors/` with whatever content and style you want. I've just done that...

[image: Custom 404 page in Laravel]

Answer (score 0):

Otherwhise

> define a fallback route at the end of the routes/api.php file:

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found.'], 404); 
})->name('api.fallback.404');
```

[Source](https://laravel-news.com/404-responses-laravel-api)

Answer (score 0):

**Try these steps:**

*1) In the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file, modify the render method.*

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

*2) Create a new view file errors/404.blade.php.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page not found - 404</title>
</head>
<body>
The page your are looking for is not available
</body>
</html>
```